# Why is xsl:copy-of not working for me?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following XSLT which wraps three specific elements and then renames some more nodes. The problem is that it only wraps the initial elements and the next part of the XSLT does not run. If I comment out the wrap part of the XSLT the rename is done without error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <!-- identity rule Copy all elements and attributes from the source to the target -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- Wrap Element   -->
    <xsl:template match="/dataroot/qryXMLOrders">

        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="PreDocTypAR21/preceding-sibling::*"/>
            <PREADMREFAR2>
                <xsl:copy-of select="PreDocTypAR21|PreDocRefAR26|PreDocCatPREADMREF21"/>
            </PREADMREFAR2>

            <xsl:copy-of select="PreDocCatPREADMREF21/following-sibling::*"/>
        </xsl:copy>

    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="/dataroot/qryXMLOrders/DocTypDC21A">
        <DocTypDC21>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </DocTypDC21>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/dataroot/qryXMLOrders/DocRefDC23A">
        <DocRefDC23>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </DocRefDC23>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/dataroot/qryXMLOrders/DocTypDC21B">
        <DocTypDC21>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </DocTypDC21>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/dataroot/qryXMLOrders/DocRefDC23B">
        <DocRefDC23>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </DocRefDC23>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The root element is "dataroot" and all the other elements are inside the "qryXMLOrders" which repeats

So a part of the XML that I want to transform is like this

```
<dataroot generated="2017-03-11T14:06:08" xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata">
    <qryXMLOrders>
        <IteNumGDS7>1</IteNumGDS7>
        <GroMasGDS46>0.046</GroMasGDS46>
        <NetMasGDS48>0.01</NetMasGDS48>
        <ProReqGDI1>10</ProReqGDI1>
        <PreProGDI1>00</PreProGDI1>
        <ComNatProGIM1>000</ComNatProGIM1>
        <StaValAmoGDI1>17.04</StaValAmoGDI1>
        <PreDocTypAR21>380</PreDocTypAR21>
        <PreDocRefAR26>6376</PreDocRefAR26>
        <PreDocCatPREADMREF21>Z</PreDocCatPREADMREF21>
        <DocTypDC21>N380</DocTypDC21>
        <DocRefDC23>6376</DocRefDC23>
        <DocTypDC21A>Y900</DocTypDC21A>
        <DocRefDC23A>-</DocRefDC23A>
        <DocTypDC21B>Y922</DocTypDC21B>
        <DocRefDC23B>-</DocRefDC23B>
        <ComNomCMD1>71171900</ComNomCMD1>
        <TARCodCMD1>00</TARCodCMD1>
        <TARFirAddCodCMD1>0000</TARFirAddCodCMD1>
        <TARSecAddCodCMD1>0000</TARSecAddCodCMD1>
        <NAtAddCodCMD1>0000</NAtAddCodCMD1>
        <NamCE27>Martha</NamCE27>
        <StrAndNumCE222>apt 5F</StrAndNumCE222>
        <PosCodCE223>10034</PosCodCE223>
        <CitCE224>New York</CitCE224>
        <CouCE225>US</CouCE225>
        <NADLNGGICE>EN</NADLNGGICE>
        <MarNumOfPacGS21>RE5935</MarNumOfPacGS21>
        <KinOfPacGS23>EN</KinOfPacGS23>
        <NumOfPacGS24>1</NumOfPacGS24>
        <InvoiceDate>2017-03-10T00:00:00</InvoiceDate>
    </qryXMLOrders>
    <qryXMLOrders>
        <IteNumGDS7>1</IteNumGDS7>
        <GroMasGDS46>0.046</GroMasGDS46>
        <NetMasGDS48>0.01</NetMasGDS48>
        <ProReqGDI1>10</ProReqGDI1>
        <PreProGDI1>00</PreProGDI1>
        <ComNatProGIM1>000</ComNatProGIM1>
        <StaValAmoGDI1>18.85</StaValAmoGDI1>
        <PreDocTypAR21>380</PreDocTypAR21>
        <PreDocRefAR26>6379</PreDocRefAR26>
        <PreDocCatPREADMREF21>Z</PreDocCatPREADMREF21>
        <DocTypDC21>N380</DocTypDC21>
        <DocRefDC23>6379</DocRefDC23>
        <DocTypDC21A>Y900</DocTypDC21A>
        <DocRefDC23A>-</DocRefDC23A>
        <DocTypDC21B>Y922</DocTypDC21B>
        <DocRefDC23B>-</DocRefDC23B>
        <ComNomCMD1>71171900</ComNomCMD1>
        <TARCodCMD1>00</TARCodCMD1>
        <TARFirAddCodCMD1>0000</TARFirAddCodCMD1>
        <TARSecAddCodCMD1>0000</TARSecAddCodCMD1>
        <NAtAddCodCMD1>0000</NAtAddCodCMD1>
        <NamCE27>fgfgfgf</NamCE27>
        <StrAndNumCE222>507 E Water St</StrAndNumCE222>
        <PosCodCE223>77901-9257</PosCodCE223>
        <CitCE224>Victoria</CitCE224>
        <CouCE225>US</CouCE225>
        <NADLNGGICE>EN</NADLNGGICE>
        <MarNumOfPacGS21>RE59357</MarNumOfPacGS21>
        <KinOfPacGS23>EN</KinOfPacGS23>
        <NumOfPacGS24>1</NumOfPacGS24>
        <InvoiceDate>2017-03-10T00:00:00</InvoiceDate>
    </qryXMLOrders>
</dataroot>
```

and the desired result after XSLT:

```
<dataroot generated="2017-03-11T14:06:08" xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata">
    <qryXMLOrders>
        <IteNumGDS7>1</IteNumGDS7>
        <GroMasGDS46>0.046</GroMasGDS46>
        <NetMasGDS48>0.01</NetMasGDS48>
        <ProReqGDI1>10</ProReqGDI1>
        <PreProGDI1>00</PreProGDI1>
        <ComNatProGIM1>000</ComNatProGIM1>
        <StaValAmoGDI1>17.04</StaValAmoGDI1>
        <PREADMREFAR2>
            <PreDocTypAR21>380</PreDocTypAR21>
            <PreDocRefAR26>6376</PreDocRefAR26>
            <PreDocCatPREADMREF21>Z</PreDocCatPREADMREF21>
        </PREADMREFAR2>
        <DocTypDC21>N380</DocTypDC21>
        <DocRefDC23>6376</DocRefDC23>
        <DocTypDC21>Y900</DocTypDC21>
        <DocRefDC23>-</DocRefDC23>
        <DocTypDC21>Y922</DocTypDC21>
        <DocRefDC23>-</DocRefDC23>
        <ComNomCMD1>71171900</ComNomCMD1>
        <TARCodCMD1>00</TARCodCMD1>
        <TARFirAddCodCMD1>0000</TARFirAddCodCMD1>
        <TARSecAddCodCMD1>0000</TARSecAddCodCMD1>
        <NAtAddCodCMD1>0000</NAtAddCodCMD1>
        <NamCE27>Martha</NamCE27>
        <StrAndNumCE222>apt 5F</StrAndNumCE222>
        <PosCodCE223>10034</PosCodCE223>
        <CitCE224>New York</CitCE224>
        <CouCE225>US</CouCE225>
        <NADLNGGICE>EN</NADLNGGICE>
        <MarNumOfPacGS21>RE5935</MarNumOfPacGS21>
        <KinOfPacGS23>EN</KinOfPacGS23>
        <NumOfPacGS24>1</NumOfPacGS24>
        <InvoiceDate>2017-03-10T00:00:00</InvoiceDate>
    </qryXMLOrders>
    <qryXMLOrders>
        <IteNumGDS7>1</IteNumGDS7>
        <GroMasGDS46>0.046</GroMasGDS46>
        <NetMasGDS48>0.01</NetMasGDS48>
        <ProReqGDI1>10</ProReqGDI1>
        <PreProGDI1>00</PreProGDI1>
        <ComNatProGIM1>000</ComNatProGIM1>
        <StaValAmoGDI1>18.85</StaValAmoGDI1>
        <PREADMREFAR2>
            <PreDocTypAR21>380</PreDocTypAR21>
            <PreDocRefAR26>6379</PreDocRefAR26>
            <PreDocCatPREADMREF21>Z</PreDocCatPREADMREF21>
        </PREADMREFAR2>
        <DocTypDC21>N380</DocTypDC21>
        <DocRefDC23>6379</DocRefDC23>
        <DocTypDC21>Y900</DocTypDC21>
        <DocRefDC23>-</DocRefDC23>
        <DocTypDC21>Y922</DocTypDC21>
        <DocRefDC23>-</DocRefDC23>
        <ComNomCMD1>71171900</ComNomCMD1>
        <TARCodCMD1>00</TARCodCMD1>
        <TARFirAddCodCMD1>0000</TARFirAddCodCMD1>
        <TARSecAddCodCMD1>0000</TARSecAddCodCMD1>
        <NAtAddCodCMD1>0000</NAtAddCodCMD1>
        <NamCE27>fgfgfgf</NamCE27>
        <StrAndNumCE222>507 E Water St</StrAndNumCE222>
        <PosCodCE223>77901-9257</PosCodCE223>
        <CitCE224>Victoria</CitCE224>
        <CouCE225>US</CouCE225>
        <NADLNGGICE>EN</NADLNGGICE>
        <MarNumOfPacGS21>RE59357</MarNumOfPacGS21>
        <KinOfPacGS23>EN</KinOfPacGS23>
        <NumOfPacGS24>1</NumOfPacGS24>
        <InvoiceDate>2017-03-10T00:00:00</InvoiceDate>
    </qryXMLOrders>
</dataroot>
```

Thanks a lot,
Nikos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have templates matching the wrapped nodes, you need to use `xsl:apply-templates` instead of `xsl:copy-of` in the template that does the wrapping.